# SendGrid unique link click count

Tags: sendgrid, click-tracking

I am sending multiple emails to multiple recipients.

Each email has multiple links, but the link URLs remain the same.

Sendgrid shows that the dashboard can report the number of opens, unique clicks, total clicks, etc.

Can SendGrid report the number of times each **unique** link has been cumulatively clicked?

Example:

- One of the links in my email is `https://www.MyVeryUniqueButFakeLink.org`
  How many times has `https://www.MyVerySpecificButFakeLink.org` been clicked on by all recipients of all emails
- Similarly I also want to know how times another link, `https://www.AnotherVerySpecificButFakeLink.org`, has been clicked on by all recipients of all emails

Can SendGrid summarize this automatically in a single dashboard view like Klaviyo does (a list of URLs with corresponding click counts)?